# Specs2 - Ignoring properties in a matcher with Future of a set of results

Tags: scala, spray, specs2, spray-json

I have the following this matcher:

```
def haveBodyWith[T: TypeTag: Unmarshaller](content: T)(implicit await: Duration): Matcher[Future[HttpResponse]] = {
    ===(content) ^^ { (f: Future[HttpResponse]) => { Await.result(f, await).entity.as[T].right.get } }
}
```

I extract the result from the HttpResponse and then compare it to the expected content. This far, this matcher worked perfectly. Now, I have a specific use case where the content of the response is a sequence of case classes, and I want to ignore one of the properties of the case class. I can't get this work:

```
def haveBodyWith(content: Foo): Matcher[HttpResponse] = {
  ===(content) ^^ { (_: HttpResponse).entity.as[Foo].right.get.copy(name = "") }
}

case class Foo(id: Int, name: String)
```

If I had just the content without the future to compare, I'd done it this way (maybe something similar with a Seq of case classes), but the future make it a little more difficult.
What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion happened on [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specs2-users/slc7bYB_ozE) and the final solution is:

```
def haveBodyWith1(content: Foo): Matcher[Future[HttpResponse]] = {
  ===(normalize(content)) ^^ { (response: HttpResponse) => 
    normalize(response.foo) }
}.await

def normalize(foo: Foo) = foo.copy(name = "")
```